# Sort content in textfile with python

Tags: python, sorting, text-files

I read a text file. And the contents, I removed punctuation's,changed all to lower case and finally, i printed each word on a new line. But the problem I am having now is sorting these contents alphabetically which afterwards, i'm to save in a new textfile. Right now, I am unable to use the (sort method), each time i type the .method-accessifier, it does not how me the sort method. SO my question is, after the earlier text manipulations which i've done as stated above, how do I sort them alphabetically?

```
punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
no_punct = ""

#Open file
file = "research.txt"
f = open(file , 'r+')

#read file
contentOfFile = f.read()


#Remove punctuations from file content
for char in contentOfFile:
   if char not in punctuations:
       no_punct = (no_punct + char)


#print "Output of formatted document is"
for word in no_punct.lower().split():
    print word
```

With the above and subsequent help I got, i was finally able to achieve milestones. But I noticed, if i print on console, it prints out fine, but when I try to create new file and save words to appear just as it appears on console, the words aren't formatted when saved in new file. But rather, all the words are saved in one long straight line. After creating new textfile called "newFile.txt", all I added nf.write(word). I thought this automatically would add each words into textFile formatted and each on new line. Is this wrong? Thank you.

```
 punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
no_punct = ""

#Open file
file = "research.txt"
f = open(file , 'r+')


#read file
contentOfFile = f.read()


#Remove punctuations from file content
for char in contentOfFile:
   if char not in punctuations:
       no_punct = (no_punct + char)


#create new file to save formatted words to
newFile = "newFile.txt"
nf = open(newFile , 'w+')


#write words to the new textFile
for word in sorted(no_punct.lower().split()):
    nf.write(word)


    #print word
```

Comment: @ZdaR, what do you mean by `sort(list)`? There is no `sort` built-in function.

Comment: Do you want to sort each individual word or each line alphabetically?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I was not very clear in my explaining. Although, my question got answered by @pschill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sorted`:

```
for word in sorted(no_punct.lower().split()):
    print word
```

If you want to write the result into a file line by line, you can try this:

```
with open("newFile.txt", "w") as f:
    for word in sorted(no_punct.lower().split()):
        f.write(word + os.linesep)
```

Of course you need to add `import os` at the beginning of your file, so that the newline character `os.linesep` is found.

Comment: and saving this new sorted words into a text file? How do I go about it? Do i just used this format  'f = open("newText.txt", "w")'

Comment: @user3761841 I updated my answer and included code to write the result into a file.

Answer (score -1):

```
word_in_file = no_punct.lower().split()
word_in_file.sort()
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Looking at my score I think the answer is no :p what does not work?

Comment: Actually it did. I used the answer from the user above though. Yours printed them out alphabetically indeed but a requirement is that each word has to be printed on a new line. But that said, yours worked fine. Thanks...